# Delphi OLEObject parent window

Tags: delphi

I am loading adobe acrobat professional using delphi. How I can set parent for oleobject to run acrobat inside my own application window?

```
PDFDoc := CreateOleObject('AcroExch.App');
PDFDoc.show;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a embedded Activex Control in your Delphi App you can use the [`TOleContainer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.OleCtnrs.TOleContainer)component. like so

```
  OleContainer1.CreateObject('AcroExch.App', False);
```